# Adding zeros to given positions in a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array and I want a function that takes as an input the numpy array and a list of indices and returns as an output another array which has the following property: a zero has been added to the initial array just before the position of each of the indices of the origional array.

Let me give a couple of examples:

If `indices = [1]` and the initial array is `array([1, 1, 2])`, then the output of the function should be `array([1, 0, 1, 2])`.

If `indices = [0, 1, 3]` and the initial array is `array([1, 2, 3, 4])`, then the output of the function should be `array([0, 1, 0, 2, 3, 0, 4])`.

I would like to do it in a vectorized manner without any for loops.

Comment: Have you tried `np.insert`?

Comment: Particularly, `np.insert([1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 3], 0)` is `[0, 1, 0, 2, 3, 0, 4]` ([see docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.insert.html)).

Comment: It works, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had the same issue before. Found a solution using [np.insert](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.insert.html):

```
import numpy as np
np.insert([1, 1, 2], [1], 0)

>>> [1, 0, 1, 2]
```

I see @jdehesa has commented this already but adding as a permanent answer for future visitors.